# How to create a file in external storage and set permission programmatically

Tags: java, android, service, background-service

I am trying to have a local backup of a database of my app in the device storage. I created a backup file/directory, but I want user to restrict from being able to copy/delete the file/directory from the device.

Is it possible to achieve this through code, using a service which I am running?

Comment: Are you trying to restrict copy/paste from another application such as a file explorer?

Comment: That is not possible. Unless you make a backup in getFilesDir(). The same place where your db resides now.

Comment: @Jordan yes.Also Its ok if I am able to hide it as well.But I tried to add a (.) before the directory name, but its visible in file explorer.

Comment: @greenapps I want to have a db backup which the user will be able to load the data next time he installs our app.So I dont want it to be deleted on uninstall also the device is rooted.

Comment: Then that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Method to check if user has permissions to write on external storage or not.**

```
public static boolean canWriteOnExternalStorage() {
// get the state of your external storage
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
 // if storage is mounted return true
  Log.v(“sTag”, “Yes, can write to external storage.”);
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

and then let’s use this code to actually write to the external storage:

```
// get the path to sdcard
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
// to this path add a new directory path
File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + “/your-dir-name/”);
// create this directory if not already created
dir.mkdir();
// create the file in which we will write the contents
File file = new File(dir, “My-File-Name.txt”);
FileOutputStream os = outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
String data = “This is the content of my file”;
os.write(data.getBytes());
os.close();
```

You need the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE” />
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: I have done this steps.I am able to copy the db file,but I am not able to set the permission to the directory to make it hidden/not deletable.